# Uncaught TypeError when calling a Javascript Function in Android

Tags: javascript, android

I am an Android developer and new to JavaScript. I am controlling the webview from my activity using javascript. In my login page when I use the Java Script functions I getting some huge errors. Please guide me to avoid these errors.

Code:

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"umail\").value = \""
        + email + "\";");
web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"password\").value = \""
        + pwd + "\";");
web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"confirmpassword\").value = \""
        + confirm_pwd + "\";");
web.loadUrl("javascript:func_register_step1('signin')");

web.loadUrl("javascript:window.JSInterface.getErrorMSG(document.getElementById('errormessagetd').innerHTML);");
web.loadUrl("javascript:window.JSInterface.getWarningMSG(document.getElementById('warning_msg').innerHTML);");
```

Error:

```
05-15 11:52:28.310: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:28.310: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:28.310: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:28.310: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught ReferenceError: func_register_step1 is not defined at null:1
05-15 11:52:28.310: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:28.310: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:31.240: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:31.240: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:31.240: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:31.240: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught ReferenceError: func_register_step1 is not defined at null:1
05-15 11:52:31.250: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:31.250: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:33.590: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:33.590: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:33.590: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:33.590: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught ReferenceError: func_register_step1 is not defined at null:1
05-15 11:52:33.600: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:33.600: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:40.260: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:40.270: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:40.270: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:40.270: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught ReferenceError: func_register_step1 is not defined at null:1
05-15 11:52:40.270: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:40.270: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:41.290: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:41.290: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:41.290: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:41.290: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught ReferenceError: func_register_step1 is not defined at null:1
05-15 11:52:41.290: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
05-15 11:52:41.290: E/Web Console(3722): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at null:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the thrown errors, it seems that `document.getElementById(...)` returns null. And so applying `.value` and `.innerHTML` to null throw the errors.

I suspect the page is not loaded when you call your javascript function. When do you call your javascript, I mean in which method? To be sure the page is loaded, you can call `loadUrl` in the `onPageFinished` method of the `WebViewClient` object.

Comment: Yes you are correct. There was an error in my webpage and I am trying to call the function.